# How to get distinct results from a Mongoid criteria?

Tags: mongoid

I am very frustrated as I try to query the results of a Mongoid criteria and keep only the documents where a field is distinct. And doing this:

```
Books.all.distinct(:name)
```

..only returns the name fields, not the documents.

Also using the `uniq` loop as stated in another question here does not work for me.

```
Books.all.uniq{|x| x.name} # Returns non-unique results
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the database layer, instead of filtering it in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

OP, your problem is that you want every book with a unique name.

This issue with this is that lets say you have 98 unique books, and 2 books with the same name

If you ask your database: "Give me every uniquely named book" It will find the first 98 books, then it will run into the last two.

Which of the two books with the same name should it return? Since there's no right answer to this question given the level of detail, something like a hypothetical .uniq does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are attempting to achieve? Does the 'name' field in your database have a unique constraint on it?

If so, you are simply retrieving all of the books names, to retrieve the books themselves you would call the base object.

If not, there will be multiple books for each name, which doesn't make sense to grab with distinct. Perhaps what you're looking for is a groupby function? To group all of the books with the same name you can call `Books.all.group_by{|book| book.name}`, but as this is run against the web server rather than at a database level it will be very slow for any reasonable amount of records.

Your best bet is probably to do one of the following:

- Use map/reduce as mentioned in the answer to this question: [Mongoid Group By or MongoDb group by in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014009/mongoid-group-by-or-mongodb-group-by-in-rails)
- Look into the new aggregation framework released in 2.2 - see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/ NOTE: At the time of writing this is not supported by Mongoid, and will take some work to get going