# Mongoid Group By or MongoDb group by in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a mongo table that has statistical data like the following....

- course_id
- status `which is a string, played or completed`
- and timestamp information using [Mongoid's Timestamping feature](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#timestamps)

so my class is as follows...

```
class Statistic
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

  field :course_id, type: Integer
  field :status, type: String # currently this is either play or complete
```

I want to get a daily count of total # of plays for a course.  So for example...
8/1/12 had 2 plays, 8/2/12 had 6 plays. Etc.  I would therefore be using the created_at timestamp field, with course_id and action.  The issue is I don't see a group by method in Mongoid. I believe mongodb has one now, but I'm unsure of how that would be done in rails 3.

I could run through the table using each, and hack together some map or hash in rails with incrementation, but what if the course has 1 million views, retrieving and iterating over a million records could be messy.  Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: About 3 things wrong/suspect there: 1) Why are you using mongo for this? And don't say "cause it's cool"; 2) Grouping in mongo is typically done through map/reduce, not through a call like in an RDBMS-backed app; 3) Does the course have a million views now? If not and it's straightforward to aggregate in ruby, do it. Worry about scale if/when it comes.

Comment: if you can use 2.2 then you can use aggregation framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you can use map/reduce for this purpose. So you could define the following method in your model ( http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#map_reduce )

```
def self.today
  map = %Q{
    function() {
      emit(this.course_id, {count: 1})
    }
  }

  reduce = %Q{
    function(key, values) {
      var result = {count: 0};
      values.forEach(function(value) {
        result.count += value.count;
      });
      return result;
    }
  }

  self.where(:created_at.gt => Date.today, status: "played").
    map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true)
end
```

which would result in following result:

```
[{"_id"=>1.0, "value"=>{"count"=>2.0}}, {"_id"=>2.0, "value"=>{"count"=>1.0}}]
```

where `_id` is the `course_id` and `count` is the number of plays.

There is also dedicated [group](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group) method in MongoDB but I am not sure how to get to the bare mongodb collection in Mongoid 3. I did not have a chance to dive into code that much yet.

You may wonder why I emit a document `{count: 1}` as it does not matter that much and I could have just emitted empty document or anything and then always add 1 to the result.count for every value. The thing is that reduce is not called if only one emit has been done for particular key (in my example `course_id` has been played only once) so it is better to emit documents in the same format as result.

Answer (score 4):

**Using Mongoid**

```
stages =  [{ 
         "$group" => {  "_id" => { "date_column_name"=>"$created_at" }},
         "plays_count" => { "$sum" => 1 }
    }]
@array_of_objects = ModelName.collection.aggregate(stages, {:allow_disk_use => true})
```

**OR**

```
stages =  [{ 
          "$group" => {  
             "_id" => { 
                       "year" => { "$year" => "$created_at" },
                       "month" => { "$month" => "$created_at" },
                       "day" => { "$dayOfMonth" => "$created_at" }
              }
           },
          "plays_count" => { "$sum" => 1 }
    }]
@array_of_objects = ModelName.collection.aggregate(stages, {:allow_disk_use => true})
```

**Follow the links below to group by using mongoid**

https://taimoorchangaizpucitian.wordpress.com/2016/01/08/mongoid-group-by-query/
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/