# How to group results with Mongoid and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

I have a model Event that is connected to MongoDB using Mongoid:

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :user_name,   type: String
  field :action,      type: String
  field :ip_address,  type: String

  scope :recent,  -> { where(:created_at.gte => 1.month.ago) }    
end
```

Usually when I use ActiveRecord, I can do something like this to group results:

```
@action_counts  = Event.group('action').where(:user_name =>"my_name").recent.count
```

And I get results with the following format:

```
{"action_1"=>46, "action_2"=>36, "action_3"=>41, "action_4"=>40, "action_5"=>37}
```

What is the best way to do the same thing with Mongoid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to use map/reduce to do that. Look at this SO question for more details:

[Mongoid Group By or MongoDb group by in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014009/mongoid-group-by-or-mongodb-group-by-in-rails?rq=1)

Otherwise, you can simply use the `group_by` method from `Enumerable`. Less efficient, but it should do the trick unless you have hundreds of thousands documents.

**EDIT: Example of using map/reduce in this case**

I'm not really familiar with it but by reading the docs and playing around I couldn't reproduce the exact same hash you want but try this:

```
def self.count_and_group_by_action
  map = %Q{
    function() {
      key = this.action;
      value = {count: 1};
      emit(key, value);
      # emit a new document {"_id" => "action", "value" => {count: 1}}
      # for each input document our scope is applied to
    }
  }

  # the idea now is to "flatten" the emitted documents that
  # have the same key. Good, but we need to do something with the values
  reduce = %Q{
    function(key, values) {
      var reducedValue = {count: 0};
      # we prepare a reducedValue
      # we then loop through the values associated to the same key,
      # in this case, the 'action' name
      values.forEach(function(value) {
        reducedValue.count += value.count; # we increment the reducedValue - thx captain obvious
      });
      # and return the 'reduced' value for that key,
      # an 'aggregate' of all the values associated to the same key
      return reducedValue;
    }
  }

  self.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true)
  # we apply the map_reduce functions
  # inline: true is because we don't need to store the results in a collection
  # we just need a hash
end
```

So when you call:

```
Event.where(:user_name =>"my_name").recent.count_and_group_by_action
```

It should return something like:

```
[{ "_id" => "action1", "value" => { "count" => 20 }}, { "_id" => "action2" , "value" => { "count" => 10 }}]
```

Disclaimer: I'm no mongodb nor mongoid specialist, I've based my example on what I could find in the referenced SO question and Mongodb/Mongoid documentation online, any suggestion to make this better would be appreciated.

Resources:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/
http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#map_reduce

[Mongoid Group By or MongoDb group by in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014009/mongoid-group-by-or-mongodb-group-by-in-rails?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @mlainez, very helpful. But can you provide me of how to generate that using map/reduce as I'm still new to Mongoid?

Comment: Done, just as it says at the bottom, I'm no expert, but at least it gives you something to start with.